# Javascript Callback Function not working from the included js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback

The Call back function works in Console ( when I run the code on Console but in a script file it is not working

```js
define(['jquery'],function($){

function calc(x,y,aa){
console.log("--",aa,"--");
  aa(x,y);
}
  function add(x,y){
 return parseInt(x+y);
}
function sub(x,y){
 return parseInt(x-y);
}
function div(x,y){
 return x/y;
}
return calc;

});

and then
$('#calcbutton').click(function(){

  var val1 = Number($('#var1').val()),
      val2 = Number($('#var2').val()),
      opper = $('#opp').val(),
      opp = opper.trim(),
      result = $('#result'),
      num1 = $.trim(val1),
      num2 = $.trim(val2);
  var aa = calculator(val1,val2,add);

});
```

The same exaple works if I am running it from console.log and I am getting an Error app.js:22 Uncaught ReferenceError: add is not defined(…)

Comment: Where is `calculator` defined? What is `add`? Can you include `html` at Question?

Comment: Do you know what `define` is? Where did it come from, why do you use it? Do you know what it does?